# Performance is bad when using HorizontalPager + LazyVerticalGrid in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I setup a really small project for testing purposes and I see a lot of janky frames when swiping the horizontalPager:
https://github.com/DaFaack/ComposePerformanceTest

I build in release mode with R8 enabled.
What am I doing wrong?

When I record the trace and view it in perfetto it shows me a lot of jank:
[image]

The same setup in XML with ViewPager + RecyclerView is running smoothly

I tried generating baseline profiles but see no difference, still janky frames

Comment: I have the same problem, it's very laggy. Have you fixed this issue yet?

Answer (score 0):

I came across same issue ,
try use R8 , follow the following link :
https://medium.com/@stefma/what-is-r8-and-how-we-enabled-it-4f5764a7ff9c

use release on physical device instead of debug

use list.forEach instead of items

use key

use baseline profiler ( i did't try it yet )

update compose library to 1.5

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

rather than using:

```
LazyVerticalGrid(columns = GridCells.Fixed(5), content = {
        items(40) {
            ImageItem(imageUrl, name)
        }
    })
```

use:

```
(0..40).forEach { it ->
    item(key: /*Create an constant key for each item*/) {
        ImageItem(imageUrl, name)
    }
}
```

I have read somewhere that using foreach on lists greatly increases performance along with custom keys. Additionally, try to use fastForEach in any possible scenario.

Comment: Of course using a forEach will be faster, but how can he improve the performance using the LazyVerticalGrid?